# CKEditor 4 saving HTML to database

Tags: html, sql, content-management-system, ckeditor, asp.net-4.0

Thanks for looking at my question in advance.

I am trying to save the contents of the ckeditor into a database. I am getting the following error:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$rightContent$ctl00$txtContent="<p> Look for a pla...").
```

I have done some research and most of the solutions are for older versions of the software or are unsecure.

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 and would appreciate any advice.

Comment: try these: [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: Did that solve the issue? This is very common. Just disable the default checks and write your own Html filter attribute or such.