# Html-element-like string gets removed from string in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mono

When I put in a string like `abc<def>ghi` in my text box, when I reach the code behind, the textbox.Text has become `abcghi`, so `<def>` got removed.

There are no Attributes on the textbox.

Does anyone know if this is default behavior, or if this is a .net setting in my config?

I have never seen this before.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="_user" runat="server" MaxLength="100" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>

foreach (char c in _user.Text.ToCharArray())
    if (invalidChars.Contains(c))
        return false;
```

Comment: You should not be seeing that behavior. Can you show us all relevant code (setting/getting/using the `Text` property)? Is there anything affecting the element client-side? Can you show us the markup for your textbox?

Comment: I updated the first post.

Comment: Do you have more than just a snippet? The whole code-behind (less anything irrelevant) would be ideal...

Comment: I do not want to put company code on the web. This is really all i am doing. there are no modifiers in the code or the front end regarding this text box. that's why i am wondering if there is a config setting somewhere. i inherited this code and am starting to figure things out.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `Server.HtmlEncode(TextBox1.text)`. More details about `HtmlEncode` is avilable [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

When you want to display the input back to the user you can do

```
Server.HtmlDecode(inputvalue)
```

**Updated..**
Use `ValidateRequest="false"` in your page directive. This might come with some security implication but you'll actually get the textbox value in code behind even if it contains HTML characters.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ValidateRequest="false" ...
```

You can access the actual value like

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string value = TextBox1.Text;
 }
```

Comment: I debugged the value in the codebehind, the actual text field says it's gone.

Comment: what do you mean? do you get the value you want in the code behind or not?

Comment: If i debug and hit my breakpoint and i check. _user.Text it's not there. it says abcghi i don't see the < > in there

Comment: so you want `abc<def>ghi` in your code behind as the textbox value?

Comment: Exactly, that's exactly what i would expect to see.

Comment: When you say "check", are you just hovering over the property, viewing it in the Quick Watch window, as a Watch variable, in the Immediate Expression box, etc.?

Comment: Edited my answer, this should get you what you want

Comment: Watch variable. and hovering over.

Comment: @DennisR: There's an additional step if .NET 4+ (http://stackoverflow.com/a/17591548/74757).

Comment: Thanks @Cory for the link. I'm using .NET 4.5 and I don't have any specific setting in my web.config as noted in the post but still works good with just `ValidateRequest="false"` at the page directive. But I do remember I had to set that flag in web.config for one of my earlier applications using .NET 4.0

Comment: it seems we have ValidateRequest="false"  in our web.config pages section. that would mean it would be used over all pages.

Comment: It should. I tried locally with `ValidateRequest="false"` set at the page level and it works perfectly (I get the actual value including HTML tags). if it doesn't work for you then it could be something else.