# How to validate Request.RawUrl in Application_BeginRequest event in Global.asax.cs file?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, request-validation, rawurl

Some bots are requesting URLs like `www.example.com/test-</p><p>they-are-angry...` which is creating `A potentially dangerous exception` in my asp.net application.

I need to validate the `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` in `Application_BeginRequest` event of `Global.asax.cs` file and if it is invalid I will redirect to another error page.

I do NOT want to set `validateRequest="false"` or [`requestValidationMode="2.0"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) but want to redirect to a particular error page if Request.RawUrl is invalid.

How to achieve this? Is there any Asp.Net predefined method to validated this URL?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just redirect to an error page, you can simply configure customErrors or implement global error handlers as detailed in [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6508415/application-error-not-firing-when-customerrors-on/957285) and on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397417.ASPX).

However, if you want to delay validation until later, such as Application_BeginRequest, you can disable request validation and invoke it explicitly, as mentioned in [Imran's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/02/19/understanding-request-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx):

1. set requestValidationMode="2.0"

2. invoke Request.ValidateInput()

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    Request.ValidateInput();
    var q = Request.QueryString;
}
```