# A potentially dangerous Request.form value was detected from the client

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, xss, code-injection

What is this and why am i getting it when i try to login to my website?  It looks like form injection warning but from where,how, and why.  My computer doesnt have a virus or malware (that i know of)  Im running an almost brand new mac os x 10.9 and the browser im using is Google Chrome.

The full error message is as follows:

Error Message:
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (h_rm_pgs_ClientState="...rialGirls'","value":"1695...").

Where is this coming from and why?

Comment: What are the full form values?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: my form is asking for a username and a password

Comment: im also connected to a VPN (dont know if that is a factor)

Comment: Show us the full URL including parameters...

Answer (score 0):

Trace sent values by Google Chrome. Just right click and select *Inspect Element* then go to *Network* and **after that** open target page to trace and understand what happened.

I guess it happens when your browser has unwanted plugins or additional tools in your computer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have a password that contains "<".
ASP.NET returns that message from it's request validation in an attempt to stop XSS.