# How to display an error message within the form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ASP.net page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Tks.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dr.Tks" ValidateRequest="true" %>

<asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tbTech" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="15"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="SubmitForm" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="ValidateForm" CssClass="btnFancy orange logBtn btnLogIn lightLinks" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

C#:

```
public void ValidateForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strTheBody = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(tbComments.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

If I enter `<script...` in the textbox above, I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (tbComments="<script...").
```

How can I validate the textbox as I type, rather than display the default error message from ASP.net (which is not user friendly)

Comment: checkout this post for some possible fixes to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: Would this be something you could use Javascript/jQuery for?

Comment: In case they have those disabled, also wanted to include a server validation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 4.5 , you can set **ValidateRequestMode="Disabled"** on a **control**.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="tbTech" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Columns="30" Rows="15"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can resolve this issue for better user experiences. You can use JavaScript, ASP.NET Validator, Disable Request validation Feature (**not recommend** - read this:[Request Validation in ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - do it only when you **want to allow markup** otherwise there is a secuity issue), or use some other tools.

One of the ASP.NET validators could resolve your issue, and it is : **RegularExpressionValidator**. For detail please visit: [Types of Validation for ASP.NET Server Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwd43d0x(v=vs.100).aspx)

Please try this:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="RegularExpressionValidator1"
ControlToValidate="tbComments"
ValidationExpression="^([A-Za-z]|[0-9]|_)+$"
Display="Static"
EnableClientScript="true"
ErrorMessage="Please enter valid string only"
runat="server"/>
```

This will happen on client side, just like javascript.

Comment: I tried that and nothing happens when i enter invalid characters.