# Post XML data throws "A potentially dangerous Request"

Tags: asp.net, postback

Due to security concerns, this solution is not feasible for us.

[A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130186/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

How can I post XML without setting validateRequest="false" or requestValidationMode="2.0" in web.config ?

Comment: try encoding the text that you're sending to the server

Comment: And then where can I decode it? I need to make it look like XML on UI.

Comment: you can decode it when you're getting the results back from the server.

Comment: I don't get it back from the server. XML is posted back when I close popup containing XML. I tried to handle it in RaisePostBackEvent but exception is thrown before that.

Comment: how are you posting it on the server?

Comment: I have an XML value in the DB. I simply get the value and bind to a textArea. I tried intercepting with application.context.Request.Params but can't even get params.

Comment: how are you reading the value? can you post your code?